# Count incorrect in MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, mongodb-.net-driver

#### Tech:

- MongoDB 3.0.8 (MMAPv1), not sharded, dedicated cluster hosted on AWS via mLab, (primary, secondary and arbiter), 3.7GB RAM
- C# driver for MongoDB 2.3
- Connection string:

> mongodb://USER:PASS@MYMONGO1.com:1234,MYMONGO2.com:1234/DB_NAME?replicaSet=REPLICA_SET_NAME

#### Assumptions

- I have collection Products with one of the fields called Package.
- There is index: "Package": 1
- Objects from this collection are never being deleted.
- The field Package is never being updated.
- New objects are inserted from time to time.

Once a day I log a specific count on this collection (same parameters every time):

```
db.Products({"Package": "Box"}).count()
// actual code running in C#:
productsCollection.Find(p => p.Package == "Box").Count()
```

I expect the result to be the same or greater every day.
**But sometimes I get a smaller value.** The next day it becomes correct again. It reproduced on two different environments.

Example:

- Day 1: 4,563,135
- Day 2: 4,563,135
- Day 3: 4,563,124 (exactly 11 less than expected)
- Day 4: 4,563,135

I was trying to manually reproduce it both via C# and directly against Mongo, but failed (the value was always correct).

What's going on?

Comment: What are the indexes for this collection? is a sharded env, replica set?

Comment: Not sharded (first line of the post). There is index on "Package":1 (will update the question to include it)

Answer (score 2):

This is probably due to balancing round was taking place when you code was executed.
From MongoDB documentation:

> On a sharded cluster, db.collection.count() can result in an
>   inaccurate count if orphaned documents exist or if a chunk migration
>   is in progress.

More about it here: [MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/method/db.collection.count/)

To get the exact result one should use the aggregation framework queries

Comment: Thanks. As far as I know orphant documents only exist in sharded clusters. Since mine is not sharded, this is not relevant for my case.